# Karma + Mocha + React + Webpack Unexpected token import on line 1

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mocha.js, karma-mocha, create-react-app

Hey Great people of SO.

I'm using create-react-app for my project setup to skip the hassle with webpack.
Development went fine, but things gets complicated when I was going for Unit Testing. I'm trying to make a Unit Testing environment using Mocha via Karma and Reactjs. When I start my karma test runner it yields an error

```
  Chrome 57.0.2987 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
  at src/UnitTesting/index.test.js:1
```

I've been googling for hours, installing so many npm modules which I've never heard of or maybe modules that's already installed to the point where my npm start yields an error in compilation as well and to no avail...

Unit Testing is very new to me, so I'm really thankful if anyone can help me, 
here is some of my stuff

**karma.conf.js**

```js
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri Apr 21 2017 23:21:18 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['mocha'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      './src/UnitTesting/*test.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      '**/*.png',
      '**/*.jpg',
      '**/*.jpeg',
      '**/*.css',
      '**/*.svg',
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      '../src/**/*.test.js' : ['webpack']
    },

    //CUSTOM PREPROCESSORS
    customPreprocessors:{
      babelSourceMap:{
        base: 'babel',
        options:{
          presets: ['react', 'babel-preset-es2015'],
          sourceMap: 'inline'
        },
        filename: function(file){
          return file.originalPath.replace(/\.js$/, '.es5.js');
        },
        sourceFileName: function(file){
          return file.originalPath;
        }
      },
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],

    //webpack config
    webpack:{
      module:{
        loaders:[
          {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader',
         include:[
           path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
           path.join(__dirname, 'UnitTesting')
         ],
         query:{
           presets:['react', 'es2015']
         }}
        ]
      },
      watch: true,
      resolve:{
        extensions:['.js', '.jsx']
      }
    },
    webpackServer:{
      noInfo: true
    },

    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

**.babelrc**

```js
{
  "presets":["react", "babel-preset-es2015"]
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having similar issue

Comment: @Cathal Yes I've figured it out but honestly i forgot how i do it, but there is something about custom preprocessor in my karma.conf.js, I'll update my current config for you